# Can Rings (with unity) over themselves always be viewed as free modules?

Tags: ring-theory, vector-spaces, modules

Given a field $K$, we know that $K$ can be viewed as a 1-dimensional vector space over itself. Can this be extended to modules? In other words if I were to take a ring $R$ with unity and considered the module of $R$ over itself, then is this module necessarily free? In particular I was wondering if the ring of Quaternions over themselves would form a free module.

Answer (score 2):

A free $R$-module $M$ is one that admits a basis.
You can easily show that this is equivalent to saying that $M \cong \oplus_I R$, where $I$ is the cardinality of some basis. (For noncommutative rings, different bases can have different cardinalities and it could happen in particular that $\oplus_I R \cong \oplus_J R$ for different indexing sets $I$ and $J$)

In particular, $R$ is free, viewed as a (left/right) $R$-module. $\{1\}$ is a basis.

Comment: In the non commutative case, is it possible for one basis to be finite and another basis be infinite? Sorry if this question seems pedestrian.

Comment: No. It can shown using cardinal arithmetic that if a module over a ring has an infinite basis, then all bases will have the same cardinality.